# How do I stack back the data according to their row? Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a large data set like ~30000 records. I would like to extract words like "Animation", "Comedy", "Family". It is successful for me to extract the words out and delete the `id`, however I do not know how to stack the words back according to their row.

My code currently:

```
import ast, json
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader
file_name = 'xx.csv'
data = []
with open(file_name, 'r', encoding= 'unicode_escape') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    headings = next(csv_reader)

    for i in csv_reader:
        data.extend(ast.literal_eval(i[7]))
     
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
del df["id"]
print(df)
```

And it would produce result:

```
            name
0      Animation
1         Comedy
2         Family
3      Adventure
4        Fantasy
         ...
40060      Drama
40061   Thriller
40062     Action
40063      Drama
40064   Thriller
```

The large data set is in csv format, but the cell should be in json formatting.

Sample data:

```json
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does everything you need:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='unicode_escape', usecols=['name'])

result = df.to_json(orient='records')
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```